# Why do I not get a console for my CentOS6 PV DomU on CentOS6XEN4 Dom0?

Tags: centos6, xen

I am currently in the process of migrating from SLES11 SP3 as Dom0 - running the "old" xend/xm-stack to CentOS6 XEN4 running the "new" xl-stack.

I stumbled across a strange problem:
After pygrub starts up I can see the correct boot line. But: then I get this:

```
xenconsole: Could not open tty `': No such file or directory
  libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: console child [0] exited with error status 2
```

That message is repeated another time, leaving me on the console of the Dom0 with a DomU in the state "running" doing nothing. I have to kill the DomU with "xl destroy" to get back into a defined state.

On the web I found nothing useful on the topic. The CentOS6 XEN4 Wiki does only seem to cover xend/xm.

When doing the same procedure with a PV CentOS 5 DomU the DomU starts up without modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**xenconsoled** was not running. After starting it, the problem was gone.
Why it was not running is a different question...

Answer (score 2):

If you ssh into your Dom0 (Xen Core)..
Su to root... .
then do a 'xm list'  first is your Centos domU vm running? or is it powered off by defualt.

If it is you can do a 'xm start xxxxx' where xxxxx is the name that was shown in the 'xm list'

Then wait a couple of seconds and try 'xm console xxxxx'  where again xxxxx is the name of the vm your trying to console into..

Barring that try updating the dom0 XEN Core.. with '# yum update' '# yum upgrade' to pull down any updates or fixes for XEN.  or with "sudo" priviledges..

Then 'reboot' the server  and see what happes...   I had a similar issue with a VM a while back.  some times you may have to put a delay in its startup script for that VM.  So that the server has time to settle down before launching the VM's.  Expecially if you have too many VM's and a low ram / slow hard disk access server..    Mine is running on a Intel NUC Dual Core, with 8 G Ram / 7200 RPM 2.5" Drive..  I still had to throttle the VM's startups...   (Only part is at the second forgot how.. think I had to edit each vm config / ini file for that)...

Hope this helps... 
David. 
Just another comm guy on the big web of a net.

Comment: ``yum update`` was one of the first things I tried. After reboot of the XEN Dom0 I still had the same problem. since I am on the "new" stack: **xl list** shows the DomU as "r" - which is bad, since the normal state would be "b". I normally only see "r" on the Dom0 or during startup of a DomU. And no - I can not ``xl console`` on that "running" DomU. This is the first DomU and it is a brand new powerful server.

Comment: BTW: I had to serialize the startup of VMs on SLES11/SP3 with xm stack as well. That is rather a xend-problem than a performance problem (one of the reasons I want to get rid of xend). I did open an SLES SR for this and the problem was that xend was not able to manage multiple parallel temporary boot devices. These are needed in the Dom0 during startup of a DomU for copying the DomU kernel to the Dom0.

Comment: You brought me onto the right track, though. ``xl console $DOMU`` pops up with ``xenconsole: Could not open tty ...``. There is a **xenconsoled** - that should be running together with **xenstored**. Both should be started via ``/etc/init.d/xencommons`` - guess what: _xenconsoled_ was not running. After starting it manually I could connect to the console!

Comment: Excellent glad I could steer you towards a fix.   Cheers..